# Ruby Net/SSH exec - get pid of remote process

Tags: ruby, linux, ssh, net-ssh

I am launching a nohup remote script with Ruby Net/SSH.

```
Net::SSH.start(ip_address, user, options) do |ssh|
  script = File.join(remote_path, 'run_case.py')
  cmd = "nohup python #{script} #{args}  < /dev/null &"
  ssh.exec(cmd)
end
```

All `stdout` and `stderr` is saved to a file on the remote machine.

Is it possible to get the PID of the remote script so that I can kill it if needed?

**EDIT 1:**
I have modified the script as suggested.

```
Net::SSH.start(ip_address, user, options) do |ssh|
  script = File.join(remote_path, 'run_case.py')
  cmd = "nohup python #{script} #{args}  < /dev/null & echo $! > save_pid.txt"
  ssh.exec(cmd)
  pid = ssh.exec!("cat save_pid.txt")
  puts mesh_pid
end
```

It complains that it cannot find the file. Is this because the file does not exist yet? I would prefer to avoid any `sleep` command if possible

**EDIT 2:** Maybe this is not elegant but it works. I have created a second `ssh` session and used `pgrep`.

```
Net::SSH.start(ip_address, user, options) do |ssh|
  script = File.join(remote_path, 'run_case.py')
  cmd = "nohup python #{script} #{args}  < /dev/null &"
  ssh.exec(cmd)
end

Net::SSH.start(ip_address, user, options) do |ssh|
  cmd = "python #{script} #{args}"
  mesh_pid = ssh.exec!("pgrep -f '#{cmd}'")
  puts mesh_pid
end
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I've down-voted because your edit makes no sense. Did you looked even a second at the code before posting it back here?

Comment: I see. Yes, I had forgotten the change the first command. Damn copy & paste.

Comment: Does it still complain that the file can't be found?

Comment: Yes. I had used the correct command in my program, but I pasted the old one here. I logged in the VM and the file is actually there. `exec` is non blocking so I thought that the second command (`cat`) is probably executed before the file is actually created. I could use a `sleep`, but it does not seem a robust approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to determine the PID (and store it in a file) as follows:

```
Net::SSH.start(ip_address, user, options) do |ssh|
  script = File.join(remote_path, 'run_case.py')
  cmd = "nohup python #{script} #{args}  < /dev/null & echo $! > save_pid.txt"
  ssh.exec(cmd)
end
```

In a script, $! represents the PID of the last process executed. If you need to kill the process, you can do it via:

```
kill -9 `cat save_pid.txt`
rm save_pid.txt
```

Comment: Ok, it will give you the pid now, but it will hang unless you close the connection manually. Try `nohup sleep 1000 &` in your terminal to see